# jQuery: PrettyPhoto in Bootstrap isn't working

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, prettyphoto

i hope someone of you can help me, i cant get the PrettyPhoto script works in my page, here is my code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<html lang="es">
  <head>
   <script src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
   <script src="js/jqueryprettyPhoto.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="kb-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.plugins.min.js"></script>
   <script type="text/javascript" src="kb-plugin/js/jquery.themepunch.kenburn.js"></script>
   <!-- CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" >
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style-kenburner.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="kb-plugin/css/settings.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/prettyPhoto.css" type="text/css" media="screen"/>
   <!-- Fuentes especiales -->
   <link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,300,600' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'> 
   <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
   <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="/js/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <script src="/js/respond.min.js"></script>
   <![endif]-->
   </head>
```

Then my html

```
<a href="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HiaOFOMPOBc" rel="prettyPhoto" title=""><img src="images/youtube.png" alt="YouTube" /></a>
```

And for last above the end of the < /body>

```
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   

        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();
});
</script>
```

Also in console i get this error.

**Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function index3.html:318
(anonymous function)**

But doesnt works, thx for your time xD

Comment: Maybe you are using the incorrect CSS selector, try `$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto();`

Comment: Hi Gustavo, I change the selector but isnt works :S

Comment: Make sure that your JQuery .js file is acessible through the page...

Comment: Yes its acessible, also i change the url for "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js" without any changes

Comment: I better used the shadowbox.js its a very good plugin. =) Thx for your help Gustavo.